# Go: Retrieve a string from between two characters or other strings

Tags: string, go, substring

Let's say for example that I have one string, like this:

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

What Go code would be able to extract `Hello World!` from that string? I'm still relatively new to Go. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking to parse a specific pattern or format? For example, is the text always surrounded by <h1> tags, general HTML, something else entirely? There is not enough information to answer the question so I am downvoting.

Comment: It's just matching strings. If I hit one matching string and then another, then give me the stuff in the middle.

Comment: For manipulating HTML, look at [GoQuery](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) or [`golang.org/x/net/html` (formerly `go.net/html`)](https://www.godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html).

Comment: Good answer to this question is https://stackoverflow.com/a/62555190/3415984

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are lots of ways to split strings in all programming languages.

Since I don't know what you are especially asking for I provide a sample way to get the output
you want from your sample.

```
package main

import "strings"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    initial := "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"

    out := strings.TrimLeft(strings.TrimRight(initial,"</h1>"),"<h1>")
    fmt.Println(out)
}
```

In the above code you trim `<h1>` from the left of the string and `</h1>` from the right.

As I said there are hundreds of ways to split specific strings and this is only a sample to get you started.

Hope it helps, Good luck with Golang :)

DB

Comment: this is wrong as trim argument is a list of characters not a string.
if `initial := "<h1>hhhhhello</h1>"` then the result would be `ello` 
https://play.golang.org/p/HkopYJEDg9F

Comment: Ignore this answer. It works for @T145s specific case but not generally. The answer below works perfectly.

Answer (score 19):

If the string looks like whatever;START;extract;END;whatever you can use this which will get the string in between:

```
// GetStringInBetween Returns empty string if no start string found
func GetStringInBetween(str string, start string, end string) (result string) {
    s := strings.Index(str, start)
    if s == -1 {
        return
    }
    s += len(start)
    e := strings.Index(str[s:], end)
    if e == -1 {
        return
    }
    e += s + e - 1
    return str[s:e]
}
```

What happens here is it will find first index of START, adds length of START string and returns all that exists from there until first index of END.

Comment: This is the best answer but it will panic if the END is not found or if the END is also found before START, see this play link: https://play.golang.org/p/C2sZRYC15XN. That play link also includes the revision to fix this problem. I submitted this revision to SO which is under peer review.

Comment: @schollz is correct and provides a more correct answer. Copying and pasting this answer is dangerous as it will panic. However, thank you Jan for the original work.

Comment: improved answer is there : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62555190/3415984

Comment: @schollz comment is good return str[s:s+e] is require

Comment: '''
Panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:27] with length 21

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.GetStringInBetween({0x49690b, 0x15}, {0x494327?, 0x4}, {0x4943f3, 0x5})
 /tmp/sandbox2821937282/prog.go:20 +0xf0
main.main()
 /tmp/sandbox2821937282/prog.go:24 +0x38
'''

https://go.dev/play/p/ju_9M0ZZzqZ

Answer (score 6):

I improved the [`Jan Kardaš`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42331558/3415984)`s answer.
now you can find string with more than 1 character at the start and end.

```
func GetStringInBetweenTwoString(str string, startS string, endS string) (result string,found bool) {
    s := strings.Index(str, startS)
    if s == -1 {
        return result,false
    }
    newS := str[s+len(startS):]
    e := strings.Index(newS, endS)
    if e == -1 {
        return result,false
    }
    result = newS[:e]
    return result,true
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is my answer using regex. Not sure why no one suggested this safest approach

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
        "regexp"
)

func main() {
    content := "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`<h1>(.*)</h1>`)
    match := re.FindStringSubmatch(content)
    if len(match) > 1 {
        fmt.Println("match found -", match[1])
    } else {
        fmt.Println("match not found")
    }
    
}
```

Playground - https://play.golang.org/p/Yc61x1cbZOJ

Answer (score 1):

Read up on the strings package.  Have a look into the [SplitAfter](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#SplitAfter) function which can do something like this:

```
var sample = "[this][is my][string]"
t := strings.SplitAfter(sample, "[")
```

That should produce a slice something like: `"[", "this][", "is my][", "string]"`.  Using further functions for Trimming you should get your solution.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

In the [strings](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/) pkg you can use the Replacer to great affect.

```
r := strings.NewReplacer("<h1>", "", "</h1>", "")
fmt.Println(r.Replace("<h1>Hello World!</h1>"))
```

Go [play!](http://play.golang.org/p/_Pg4B7NEpt)

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question about finding the string between the tags? It only shows how to remove the tags.

Comment: My answer does exactly what the OP asked for "What Go code would be able to extract Hello World! from that string?"

Answer (score 1):

```
func findInString(str, start, end string) ([]byte, error) {
    var match []byte
    index := strings.Index(str, start)

    if index == -1 {
        return match, errors.New("Not found")
    }

    index += len(start)

    for {
        char := str[index]

        if strings.HasPrefix(str[index:index+len(match)], end) {
            break
        }

        match = append(match, char)
        index++
    }

    return match, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```go
func SplitBetween(str, bef, aft string) string {
    sa := strings.SplitN(str, bef, 2)
    if len(sa) == 1 {
        return ""
    }
    sa = strings.SplitN(sa[1], aft, 2)
    if len(sa) == 1 {
        return ""
    }
    return sa[0]
}
```

Returns empty string if split is not found.

Answer (score -1):

```
func Split(str, before, after string) string {
    a := strings.SplitAfterN(str, before, 2)
    b := strings.SplitAfterN(a[len(a)-1], after, 2)
    if 1 == len(b) {
        return b[0]
    }
    return b[0][0:len(b[0])-len(after)]
}
```

the first call of `SplitAfterN` will split the original string into array of 2 parts divided by the first found `after` string, or it will produce array containing 1 part equal to the original string.

second call of `SplitAfterN` uses `a[len(a)-1]` as input, as it is "the last item of array `a`". so either string after `after` or the original string `str`. the input will be split into array of 2 parts divided by the first found `before` string, or it will produce array containing 1 part equal to the input.

if `after` was not found than we can simply return `b[0]` as it is equal to `a[len(a)-1]`

if `after` is found, it will be included at the end of `b[0]` string, therefore you have to trim it via `b[0][0:len(b[0])-len(after)]`

all strings are case sensitive